# Solving a 2-variable differential equation using logarthmic differentiation

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations

Let $f(x,k): \mathbb{R}^2_+\rightarrow \mathbb{R}_+$ be the following function,

$$\dfrac{2kx}{x+c},$$

where $c$ is some positive constant. I'm essentially trying to figure out the ["elasticity"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elasticity_of_substitution) of this equation between variables $k$ and $x$ (this is just context, and understanding of the concept is not required for the maths).

Let $f_x$ be $df(x,k)/dx$, and $f_k$ be $df(x,k)/dk$. Then what is,

$$\frac{dln(x/k)}{dln(f_k/f_x)}?$$

---

I know that this becomes the following,

$$\frac{d(x/k)}{x/k}/\frac{d(f_k/f_b)}{f_k/f_x}$$

Given that $f_x=\frac{2kc}{(x+c)^2}$, and $f_k=\frac{2x}{x+c}$, this is

$$\frac{d(x/k)}{x/k}/\bigg(\frac{d(f_k/f_b)}{x(x+c)/kc}\bigg).$$ But how do I evaluate what's left? I'm used to derivatives, and not so much to differentiation expressions.

Comment: Are $x$ and $k$ independent variables or one of them is treated as a function of the other? If they're independent, the notation $\mathrm d(x/k)$ is illegal in such an expression.

Comment: They are variables which may or may not be independant. Read the link mentioned by the OP - they are economic input variables - they may or maynot have a dependance on each other.

Comment: @Ashish By “independent” I mean in the sense of function/mapping instead of a statistical one.

Answer (score 2):

You made an error in computing $f_k$.
\begin{align}
f_x &= \frac{2kc}{(x+c)^2} \\
f_k &= \frac{2x}{x+c} \\
\frac{f_k}{f_x} &= \frac{x(x+c)}{kc} 
\end{align}
Let $k = v(x)$ where $v(x)$ is some function of x.
\begin{align}
\Rightarrow \frac{x}{k} &= \frac{x}{v(x)} \text{ and } \frac{f_k}{f_x} = \frac{x(x+c)}{v(x)c} \\
\Rightarrow E_{xk} &= \frac{d\ln(\frac{x}{k})}{d\ln(\frac{f_k}{f_x})} = \frac{d\ln(\frac{x}{v(x)})}{d\ln(\frac{x(x+c)}{v(x)c})} \\
\Rightarrow E_{xk} &= \frac{\frac{d\ln(\frac{x}{v(x)})}{dx}}{\frac{d\ln(\frac{x(x+c)}{v(x)c})}{dx}} = \frac{(x+c)(v(x) - xv'(x))}{x(2v(x) - xv'(x)) + c(v(x) - xv'(x))}  \\
&= \frac{(x+c)u'(x)}{x(k + u'(x)) + cu'(x))} = \frac{(x+c)u'(x)}{xk + (x+c)u'(x)}
\end{align}
where $u(x) = \frac{v(x)}{x} = \frac{k}{x} \Rightarrow u'(x) = \frac{\partial \frac{k}{x}}{\partial x}$.

Hence, in such a case you can't report the elasticity without knowing rate of change of one input w.r.t to the other.

In the case where there is no functional relation w.r.t k and x, then simply equate $u'(x) = -\frac{k}{x^2}$ in the above expression.

Comment: Why do I equate $u′(x)=−k/x^2$ in the expression when there is no functional relationship?

Comment: If $x$ and $k$ are not related, then $v(x)$ is a constant function independent of x. Thus $u(x) = \frac{k}{x}$ where k is independant of x and hence $u'(x) = -\frac{k}{x^2}$.

Answer (score 2):

Since the dependence or independence of the variables $x$ and $k$ is not evident a priori I suggest considering both of them as functions of a hidden variable $t$ ("time").

Given $f(u,v):={2uv\over u+c}$ we can compute
$f_u(u,v)={2vc\over (u+c)^2}$, $\ f_v(u,v)={2u\over u+c}$.
You are interested in the quantity
$$q(t):={{d\over dt}\log\bigl(x(t)/k(t)\bigr)\over{d\over dt}\log\bigl(f_v\bigl(x(t),k(t)\bigr)/f_u\big(x(t),k(t)\bigr)\bigr)}\ .$$
After performing the necessary calculations the result can be expressed as a function of $x=x(t)$, $k=k(t)$, and the quotient ${k'(t)\over x'(t)}$ which encodes a possible dependence between the variables $x$ and $k$.